# Passing request header to response headers via Transform Rules

Tags: http, http-headers, cloudflare, request-headers, response-headers

I am trying to pass the CF-IPCountry header to my response headers.

I then go to Rules --> Transform Rules --> HTTP Response Header Modification rule

None of the following solutions work (CF throws an error - unrecognised input). What is the correct way to go about it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work like you expect.

Request headers are passed to your server; if you want to return the request header content of Request.CF-IPCOUNTRY as a Response header, your server would have to catch it and add it to its response. After that is added to the response, the Transformation at Cloudflare would allow you to remap to whatever header name you wish.